# Java program calculates average of variable array, input from command line, displays results

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, terminal, compiler-errors

Below is what I have so far. The instructions are to create a simple java program that calculates the avg of a variable quantity of ints. Args array for main, no Scanner object, find and display highest and lowest value. Static method that takes user input as argument & returns values. Should display welcome message at launch.

So I think the start of my code is correct! It compiles for me. But I'm not sure how to get user input w/o scanner. I assume I need to use an array in the static method to translate the input into an argument. Which at execution would be java CalculateAverage 1, 2, 5, 9, 20? 
And then would I call MATH? So I can display all the values of min max & avg? Am I on the right track..? The questions are specific in the code. Sorry, first time posting here!

```
public class CalculateAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Hello welcome to the Average Calculator");

    int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    //do i just keep going and adding letters til j? 
    //or is there an easier way to do this..?
    minArray(array);
    maxArray(array);
    sumArray(array);
    avgArray(array);
}

public static double maxArray(double[] array){

    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
       //tbh i saw this on a tutorial, idk if NEGATIVE_INFINITY would 
       //work for me? 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];

    System.out.println("The maximum of your array is:" + max);
}

public static double avgArray(double[] array){

    double sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    double avg = sum / n;

    System.out.println("The average value of your array is: " + avg);
} //then i would make another static for the min but probably before max
```

}

Comment: For your first time here, and posting a [Homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) question (which tend to be pretty polarizing and difficult to ask in the proper way) you did an excellent job. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: @Stephan wow thank you! I'm glad I did it right haha, tried to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, you want to execute

```
javac CalculateAverage.java
```

to have Java compile the class and prepare to run it. Then you can execute the code with

```
java CalculateAverage arg0 arg1 arg2 ...
```

Now, in your `main( string[] args )` method, I see you're creating an array with 11 elements. This is not necessary, and it is not ideal - what if the user gives more than 11 arguments when they're running the program? The better way to do this is:

```
int[] array = new int[ args.length ]()
```

This creates a new array of `int`s, of the same length as the array `args` - every array has that property `length` that states how many elements the array has. Now, we haven't actually put anything in `array` yet, but we know that it has space for the same number of arguments as the program gave. Now, to initialize each element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i])
}
```

A `for` loop creates a variable `i` (this is the `int i = 0` part), initialized to `0`, and then executes the code inside the curly brackets. After it's done, it increases the value of `i` by one (this is the `i++` part), and runs the code inside the curly brackets again, continuously, until the condition `i < args.length` is false. Altogether, this iterates through every element of `args` and initializes the corresponding element of `array`.

Now, you *could* use the `Math` module to do the calculations for you, but you're almost there in doing it yourself. Here's a slight touch-up to `maxArray`, for example:

```
public static int maxarray(int[] array) {
    int max = array[0]
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The maximum of your array is:" + max);
}
```

I'm using `int` here because the inputs were `int`s. In general you should probably make sure that everything is the same type of variable; either make all the numbers `int`s or make them all `double`s, but don't try to go back and forth between them.

You don't actually need negative infinity for anything; you can just start with the first number in your array, call that the maximum, and then for every number afterwards, replace the maximum if it's larger. We use the `for` loop in the same way here, to iterate over the entire array.

Similarly, you're doing `avgArray(double[] array)` correctly already - except that I don't know where you got the variable `n` from (you should be using `array.length` again).

Overall, I recommend looking back over your notes for this class so far, and carefully make sure you know what everything means and how it applies to this example. Review what you've been taught about how Arrays work; and about the differences between `int`s and `double`s.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering why I needed to go through and add so many values for the arrays! I even remember learning arrays.length in class it just completely slipped my mind! This compiles! But it does return with 2 errors saying "missing return statement". But if I added return max or something that would end the program, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do. Hopefully the code is simple and self-explanatory but let me know if any questions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello welcome to the Average Calculator");
    int numArgs = args.length;  //Since args is an array we can get the number of elements with .length
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  //The maximum possible value an int can be
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  //The minimum possible value an int can be
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) {
        int nextI = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        total += nextI;
        if(nextI < min) {
            min = nextI;
        }
        if(nextI > max) {
            max = nextI;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The average is: " + total/numArgs);
    System.out.println("The min is: " + min);
    System.out.println("The max is: " + max);
}
```

Then, you would run the code like this:

```
java CalculateAverages 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Hello welcome to the Average Calculator
The average is: 5.0
The min is: 1
The max is: 9
```

**Edit:**

> The instructions said "To find these value, make static methods that
>   take the user input as arguments & returns the value"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numArgs = args.length;
    int[] userIntInputs = new int[numArgs]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) {
        userIntInputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("The average is: " + getInputAverage(userIntInputs));
    System.out.println("The min is: " + getInputMin(userIntInputs));
    System.out.println("The max is: " + getInputMax(userIntInputs));
}

private static int getInputMax(int[] userIntInputs) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < userIntInputs.length; i++) {
        if(userIntInputs[i] > max) {
            max = userIntInputs[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static int getInputMin(int[] userIntInputs) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < userIntInputs.length; i++) {
        if(userIntInputs[i] < min) {
            min = userIntInputs[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

private static double getInputAverage(int[] userIntInputs) {
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < userIntInputs.length; i++) {
        total += userIntInputs[i];
    }
    return total/userIntInputs.length;
}
```

**One Method Alternative**

> Idk if she means to make a method for each value or one method!

Yeah teachers can be confusing all right.  Here's a one method approach...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numArgs = args.length;
    int[] userIntInputs = new int[numArgs]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) {
        userIntInputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    Object[] inputMetrics = getInputMetrics(userIntInputs);
    System.out.println("The average is: " + inputMetrics[0]);
    System.out.println("The min is: " + inputMetrics[1]);
    System.out.println("The max is: " + inputMetrics[2]);

}

private static Object[] getInputMetrics(int[] userIntInputs) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < userIntInputs.length; i++) {
        int nextI = userIntInputs[i];
        total += nextI;
        if(nextI < min) {
            min = nextI;
        }
        if(nextI > max) {
            max = nextI;
        }
    }
    Object[] metrics = {total/userIntInputs.length, min, max};
    return metrics;
}
```

Comment: This is great! You don't think I need to make a public avgArray and classes like that as I was doing? The instructions said "To find these value, make static methods that take the user input as arguments & returns the value". Idk if she means to make a method for each value or one method!

Comment: Methods are good and you'll need them later, I was just trying to boil it down.  I'll adjust the answer with a separate solution that's method based

Comment: ah okay! I really like the way you put it all into one, to me that makes far more sense! I might submit both and see which one is preferred!

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity is IMHO the best way. This does the whole thing:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(args)
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::parseDouble));

System.out.println("The minimum of your array is: "+ stats.getMin());
System.out.println("The maximum of your array is: "+ stats.getMax());
System.out.println("The sum of your array is: "+ stats.getSum());
System.out.println("The average of your array is: "+ stats.getAverage());
```

When there's a built-in library to handle something, use it.